# Export frequency and group to excel sheet in column after plotting by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got the nice plot but I want to export the data of x and y in column to excel sheet

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i, (f, g) in enumerate(zip(frequencies.T, gv_norm.T)):
   plt.plot(f, g 'o')
plt.show()
print (" Frequency:  %s     Group : %s " %(f, g))
```

I want to export the data frequency and group to excel in column. How to do it?

Comment: Use an external library. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is the most notorious one.

Comment: Please don't use images for code/text in your question. if you just print the two columns separated by a comma you can import the resulting text file as CSV in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) like:

```
import pandas as pd
dataTmp = {
    "col1": frequencies.T
    "col2": gv_norm.T
}
data = pd.DataFrame(dataTmp)
data.to_csv("csvName.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

Comment: I am getting this errorr.     aise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index